# Creating R-shiny app, want to use the names of people in CSV file as choices in selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

Not sure if this has been asked before. I am very new to working with RShiny apps, and I would like to use the values from a particular column of a particular CSV file for the choices in my selectInput() select box. Here is my code without the CSV, using some dummy variables.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = h4("PLAYER SELF-CENTERED RATING (PSCR)", align = "center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("selectplayer",
                  label = h3("Select box"), 
                  choices = list("Choice 1" = 3,
                                 "Choice 2" = 4,
                                 "Choice 3" = 5),
                  selected = 3)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('radarPlot', width = "100%")
    )
  )
))
```

quite frankly, I'm fairly lost w.r.t where to begin on this. I also will need to use data from the CSV file to create another dataframe that is plotted in a renderPlot() call in shinyServer, so will need to find a way to get the CSV data into both server and ui. Is this a simple task, or something difficult? any help appreciated!

Comment: see `?read.csv` to get a data.frame from your csv. Then in selectInput, changes choices to that column of your dataframe.

Comment: You should just read Your CSV data outside of ui and server, then it will be available for both of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display `uiOutput` in `ui` and dynamically generate the ui in `server`. The code below should give you a hint.

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, session, output) {

# read csv here    
datin <- read.table(text = 'Name,Age,Weight
John,10,40
Hary,20,70
Mike,30,80', 
header = TRUE, sep =",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$select_1 = renderUI({

            selectInput("select_input","select", choices = datin['Name'])

  }) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("select_1")
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: One limitation with this solution is that if the source (in this case a csv file, but it could be a database query) changes, this is not reflected when you refresh the app from browser or open it in another tab. You need to shut down the application and start again. This is annoying when you run a shiny server with users using reports, because it means that you have to restart the server, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate *dynamic* output using `uiOutput` in the sidebar as shown in the following code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "R-shiny app"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        uiOutput("columnNames") # Dynamic generate UI element
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        fluidRow(
          column(10,
                 dataTableOutput('dataview')) #Display data in the tabular form
        ),

        fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("column_value"))),
        hr()
      )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) { 
      # Read data from .csv file
      data=iris # (for understanding I am using iris dataset)
        output$column_value <- renderPrint({
          output$columnNames <- renderUI({
            selectInput("datacolumn", h4("Select Data Column"), colnames(data)) # Dynamically set selectInput
           })
          output$dataview <- renderDataTable(data,options = list(pageLength = 10)) # Display the iris dataset
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Canovice- Go through the above code and hope you will get an idea.  I have tested the above code and its working.